# SSMS - text tabs acting like spaces when using backspace

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a weird issue within SSMS where if I tab a text block over to the right, it will indent the line successfully 5 character spaces. However, when I try to delete that indention, it removes only one character space. So for instance, I have the following statement:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   Table
```

If I click Backspace in order to move the table to the left, the following happens:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
  Table
```

Notice the slight offset to the left. Typically pressing backspace would result in the following:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
Table
```

I completely wiped the settings in ..\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0 to no avail. This is on a Windows Server 2012 Environment running SQL 2012 with no add-ons. I haven't been able to find anything that references what this might be, and it perplexes me because I have other instances of SSMS on Terminal Servers that do not behave in this manner. Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Did you try pressing shift+tab?

Answer (score 3):

Is it because of this setting in Options? - default would be to "keep tabs" - it seems like you might be set to insert spaces.

[image]

UPDATE: You might also need to look at the same setting under "All Languages" as well.

Comment: I have checked these locations and it's set to "Keep tabs."